# Convert SelectedValue of Combobox to type

Tags: c#, wpf, casting

Lets say I have a string variable as,

```
string selectedvalue=ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

How to convert string to a type assuming the selectedvalue to be a class name...Thanks..

Comment: You can't convert the string to a custom class type. You can however, try and cast `SelectedValue` to whatever type you're looking for using `ComboBox1.SelectedValue as MyType`.

Comment: converting a string to a `Type` requires some info about the assembly in which the Type is defined. If the Types are defined right in the current executing assembly, then you can convert the `FullName` of the type to the corresponding `Type`. The `FullName` is combined from the namespaces and the class name.

Comment: What are the items in your `ComboBox`?  Why not just bind the `ComboBox` to a list of types so you don't need to convert the selection?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're wanting the `Assembly.GetType(String)` method, as described at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx.

Hope this helps,
Nate

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is optimal, but i think doing a switch case with the string value of your class and then doing what you want to do would work.

```
string caseSwitch = className1;
switch (caseSwitch)
{
    case "className1":
        // Do what you need to do here 
        break;
    case "className2":
        // Do what you need to do here
        break;
    default:
        // Do what you need to do here
        break;
}
```

You could create an object of the class that matches the string that is selected in the do what you need to do here part

The className could be hardcoded or given by another function. For more info on getting the name with a function, you can read this : (I am not a pro of c#) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1